# I use Shape Keys but they aren't saved in the timeline

Tags: animation, shape-keys

I use Blender 3.6.2.
I downloaded this Object(Bunny) from this link :
https://www.cgtrader.com/items/4240773/download-page

When I click on my object's head or any parts they are not selected, and when I add Shape Keys on the head then they are added successfully. But when I try to insert them into the timeline, no yellow dots appear in the timeline. So, they are not inserted successfully. In the graph, there are also not shown any Shape Keys.

this is the screenshot of my screen there are not insert the Shape key in the Timeline.

[image]

Comment: You may want to supply a [sample file with an example](https://blend-exchange.com/) of your problem.   Note that Shape key animations are stored in a separate level (key animation) from object or armature bone animation.  Nonetheless I will see the "yellow dots" in the timeline.

Comment: I’m not certain, but it sounds like you may have a misunderstanding of what a shape key is and what it does. Shape keys are not key frames. What are you doing when trying to add them to the timeline?

Comment: @TheLabCat thank you for replying my question, i know what is the shape keys and how it's working, when i try to insert shape key in the time line there are not any yellow dot are visible. so there has been not perfectly insert the key on the timeline.

Comment: @james_t thank you for replying my question, i know that Shape key animations are stored in a separate level from object or armature bone animation. 
but when i select the only head and i set the shape key on the head and when i try to insert in the timeline there are not any yellow dots are visible on the time line and as well as there are not any key selected on the graph editor. so the main problem is the head doesn't selected perfectly so how to i solved this problem.

Comment: I shared a google link in my Question. I download object(Bunny) from this link.

Comment: If an object is set to be unselectable, you will not be able to select it from the viewport but you can still select it from the outliner to see its properties, like shape keys. The issue is, all animation editors show only selected objects' keyframes by default. So you should make that object selectable first.

Comment: I don’t remember any way to directly add shape keys to the timeline. Can you show me in the manual or whatever reference material you were using how this is done?

Comment: Again, you don't add shapekeys to a timeline. The timeline shows any existing keyframes from what you select. You still have to [edit] your post to add the needed information for it to be complete. Only then we can post answers.

Comment: @L0Lock thank you for replying my questions and comments, i mentioned the screenshot in my question there are not insert the shape key in the timeline and graph editor.

Comment: @TheLabCat thank you for replying my questions and comments, i mentioned the screenshot in my question, so i used this method on my blender project.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the selection filter in the Graph editor works, but since it will show every possible keyframe in your file: the more keys you have, the more **overcrowded, difficult to use and unreadable** your animation editors will become, it can even **crash** Blender in extreme cases.  That's why it's rarely advised to use that, and if you do: you should turn it back on as soon as you are done.

Hence, the solution I would always advise is [the one I mentioned in the comments](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/310480/i-use-shape-keys-but-they-arent-saved-in-the-timeline/311021#comment538157_310480):
Make the objects selectable.

---

In the outliner, open the Filters popover, and enable the "Selectable" Restriction Toggle:

[image: picture of outliner's filters popover]

With this enabled, you will be able to see every object's selectability, and toggle it. You can toggle the head object's selectability this way:

[image: picture of head mesh objects set to selectable]

Then, as you are now able to select these object, any keyframe you add to them will be visible in animation editors when selected.

---

Bonus:

If I were you, I would actually <kbd>[image: LMB] LMB</kbd> drag my mouse over all the mesh objects selectability to toggle them all ON:

[image: animated GIF of how to drag toggle object properties]

That way, if you want to make these objects unselectable (which can be useful while doing only animation), you can toggle OFF the parent collection's selectability instead of the individual mesh objects. It's simpler to manage.

---

Bonus 2:

Good to note that, when we have a character with a rig and shapekeys, we prefer creating controls for the shapekeys inside the rig itself. It is in fact what's already being done in your rig: all the purple shapekeys are facial shapes driven by the facial bones:

[image: GIF of how moving facial bones change the shapekeys values]

There are multiple reasons for this:

- keyframes on an object's shapekeys would be stored in a different animation data block, whereas keyframes on bones controlling these shapekeys will be in the same data block as the other bones of that armature
- it prevents you from having to change object interaction modes and select different objects all the time just to be able to animate a few shapekeys
- if done well, like your facial bones: bones "feel" better to use in animation.

Answer (score 0):

When the object part is not selected and you can try to saved shape key on the timeline. so you remove the right mark on the *Only Show Selected*.

In that time your shape key will be save on the timeline.

[image]

And this is your graph editor.

[image]

In the graph editor you deselect *Arrows*, and your keys will be visible.

[image]